# How to continuously dump dumpsys meminfo into a file?

Tags: shell, adb

I am using following command to dump memory info in a file
watch -n5 'adb shell dumpsys meminfo  > meminfo.txt'

But this overwrites every time it dumps. How do i continuously dump into a file? I want to review the numbers and find a pattern of memory use.

Comment: `watch -n5 'adb shell dumpsys meminfo >> meminfo.txt'`

Comment: sweet, thanks. This worked